# What do the iPad "End of Times" books contain?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

Many of the End of Times hardback books have sold out very quickly (I believe the latest one was out of stock within seven minutes!) however there are iPad versions available.

Do the iPad versions contain just the story or do they contain the rules and scenarios as well?

Answer (score 2):

Games Workshop have replied to my email:

> Thanks for the email.
>
> I can confirm for you that the iBook contains everything that the
>   physical copy contains except the paper!
>
> I hope that this helps, but if you need anything further, please let
>   me know.
>
> Kind regards
>
> Lydia

It looks like iBook has a complete ruleset too.